# capistrano command works on server, but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano

I'm getting this error  when running this capistrano task (my own - cap deploy:show_pointers):

```
  * executing `deploy:show_pointers'
  * executing "cd /home/mydomain/public_html/site_folders/rails/current; rake app:show_pointers"
    servers: ["mydomain.net"]
    [mydomain.net] executing command
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] (in /home/mydomain/public_html/site_folders/rails/releases/20120521025150)
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: mydomain.net] Try running `bundle install`.
    command finished in 1584ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/mydomain/public_html/site_folders/rails/current; rake app:show_pointers'" on mydomain.net
```

However when I run

```
sh -c 'cd /home/mydomain/public_html/site_folders/rails/current; rake app:show_pointers
```

manually from the same dir that capistrano logs into, it works. I have capistrano set to NOT USE sudo, so that shouldn't be the issue, but it sounds like it might be, since the above command fails with sudo. I think this is a user issue, or maybe an environment var issue. Or I'm not sure what.

Any suggestsions. This is a task that is already a rake task, but it will help me not to have to log into the server every time I run it (and about 10 more like it).

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dbra over on stack overflow has pointed out that I need the full path to rake.

Answer (score 3):

> manually from the same dir that capistrano logs into, it works.

That doesn't say anything, Capistrano creates a non-login tty, which means that your profile, dot-files, etc are not run.

```
ssh root@example.de -t /bin/sh
```

This is a more reliable way to compare environments to Capistrano, (although, even this is a little more full-featured than what Capistrano is using.

Answer (score 0):

Given these error messages, I have a couple ideas:

```
** [out :: mydomain.net] Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
** [out :: mydomain.net] Try running `bundle install`.
```

The app can't find the `rake` command. Have you tried to run `bundle install` on the remote machine as its recommending?

Another option might be to change the command to

```
cd /home/mydomain/public_html/site_folders/rails/current; bundle exec rake app:show_pointers
```

Using `bundle exec` might be recommended in front of the command depending on the ruby environment on the remote servers.